# What is the meaning of 愣了愣

Tags: meaning

I have：

格兰仕空调生产车间负责人走过生产线时，看到以为一位工人正在抬起手臂取零件，她愣了愣，想：“这个动作有没有可能改进一下呢？”

她愣了愣， 想  = 'she suddenly thought', 'she, with a start, thought'  Is that the meaning of '愣了愣‘？？ Or is it 'staring at him, she thought, '

Comment: Look up Reduplication of verbs. Topic considered
before at this site.Reduplication (1)implies a short and quick action,(2)expresses an attempt or trial,(3)expresses a sense of being light and relaxed.
（２）When monosyllables are reduplicated, 一 can be inserted between the two parts, example 您说一说， 我想一想。
（３）If the aspectual particle 了 is used to emphasize the completion of an action, 了 must be placed between the two parts of the reduplicated verb

Comment: For a more complete discussion of reduplication of verbs please consult 实用现代汉语语法：第四章：动词， 第四节： 动词的重叠， １６０页－１６８页

Comment: Thanks, but I still have no idea what it means. Do you know and can you explain what it means?

Comment: It would seem that in the present case the meaning of verb reduplication mentioned under （１）（see above）
would apply，i。e。 the action of being startled （see answer below： amazed，surprised ，stunned，stupefied，［ some of these naturally might be too strong］） takes place over a short time， which is what can usually be said about being startled anyhow，therefore indicating short duration by adding e。g。＂for a moment＂ appears redundant， see the examples in iciba for 看了看，showing translation often does not specifically express short duration since it may be intrinsic to the action in question。

Comment: How about '她愣了愣，想....‘ = 'she paused for a moment and thought.....'
Deutsch 'sie hielt  für einen Moment inne und dachte ....'

Comment: 我知道了。学汉语，真的需要结合实际。有意思，有意思，真的有意思。加油！

Comment: 你值得拥有一本《汉语词典》，或者其他类型的工具书，轻松搞定一切、秒杀一切。

Answer (score 1):

愣 is used pretty common in Chinese in a couple of ways. In this situation, the lady 她 could be a little bit **shocked, amazed, and surprised**. That kind of feeling made her to stare at the scene for a moment.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't understand why she would be shocked, amazed and or surprised  just because she saw a man lift his arm.

Comment: Thanks. I do not have enough information or context to explain it. Only based on "看到一位工人正在抬起手臂取零件", and then "可能改进一下", maybe this action is not safe? It may need a HI-LO.

Answer (score 1):

愣了愣 literally means she *froze for a split second* (usually due to amazement, but can be a result of other reasons).

Answer (score 0):

It means "hesitate a little bit" because of surprise

Answer (score 0):

The reason that she feels surprise is that she finds out that works are doing loading in a wrong way. Therefore, she says "is there any possible that you can change the way you are doing". "愣了愣" means that she is surprised about the wrong action and try to correct them.